# Does the final episode have a moral?

Tags: tales-from-the-loop

In true *Twilight Zone* or *Outer Limits* fashion, many of the stories in *Tales from the Loop* have a clear moral. Sometimes this is stated outright by the characters in voice-over, such as "nothing lasts forever"  in the episode "Stasis", but more often it is just very heavily implied. In fact, the moral or theme of each episode is pretty easy to see, for most of them: "The grass is always greener on the other side of the fence" ("Transpose"), "Do not fear death" ("Echo Sphere"), "Do not wait for Prince Charming, because there is no such thing as perfect" ("Parallel").

The plot of the final episode is a bit confusing, though, with the resolution of several hanging plot threads and some time travel out of nowhere. I did not really understand the intended moral at the end.

Does this final episode have a moral? If so, what is it?

Comment: "Wheel of Morality, turn, turn, turn.  Tell us the lesson we should learn."

Comment: This one is probably opinion-based, but if I had to venture a guess, it's that "some things can't be fixed, sometimes the truth will not set you free".